# Paypal payment process issue

Tags: paypal

We are using PayPal digital goods API, and while our buyer tried to send a payment(from us), he gets the following error message.

[image: payment page screenshot]

Even we are getting the same error, while we tried this from our other account(in India).

Answer (score 0):

This may have something to do with what you are sending over.  Review what you are sending over, or if you can provide the request string that you are sending over minus your credentials I can take a look at it.  You may be passing over something that is causing the issue.

Comment: i am using this class https://github.com/thenbrent/paypal-digital-goods , can you please suggest, how to get request string?

Comment: ok I have got, I will post that in a bit, are you available to have a look?

Comment: I don't believe those files have any logging built into the code.  You would have to add a few lines of code to those files to capture the request that you are sending over to PayPal.  You could just write the request you are sending to a log/txt file.

Comment: hello, thanks for your help. Please find API request string using [this link](http://pexi.co/api-request.txt)